# weird memory error in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, realloc

I'm writing a program in C that checks for circular symbolic links. The strategy is to create a struct fileInfo:

```
typedef struct fileInfo fileInfo;

struct fileInfo {
    ino_t inode;
    dev_t devID;
};
```

that will store a file's inode and devID. We create an array of these structs and check every time before opening a new file whether the file already exists. If so, then it's a circular link.

```
void func1(...)
{

    fileInfo **fileData = malloc(sizeof(struct fileInfo*));
    int fileDataLen = 0;
    char* path = "path of file";
    /* some flags */

    func2(path, fileData, &fileDataLen);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileDataLen; i++)
        free(fileData[i]);
    free(fileData);
}

void func2(char* path, fileInfo ** fileData, int * fileDataLen)
{
    //try to open file
     struct stat buf;
     if (openFile(file, &buf, followSymLinks) == -1)
         exit(1);

     fileData = checkForLoops(fileData, fileDataLen, &buf, file);

     if (S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) 
     {
         char* newPath = /* modify path */
         func2(newPath,fileData, fileDataLen);
     }

    /* other stuff */

}

int openFile(char* file, struct stat * buf, fileInfo ** fileData, int * fileDataLen)
{

     if (lstat(path, buf) < 0) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "lstat(%s) failed\n", path);
            return -1;
        }
     return 0;
}

fileInfo** checkForLoops(fileInfo **fileData, int * fileDataLen,struct stat *buf, 
                    char* path)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (*fileDataLen); i++)
    {
        if (fileData[i]->inode == buf->st_ino && 
            fileData[i]->devID == buf->st_dev)
            fprintf(stderr, "circular symbolic link at %s\n", path);
    }


    fileInfo *currFile = malloc(sizeof(struct fileInfo));
    memcpy(&currFile->inode, &buf->st_ino, sizeof(buf->st_ino));
    memcpy(&currFile->devID, &buf->st_dev, sizeof(buf->st_dev));

    fileData[(*fileDataLen)] = currFile;
    (*fileDataLen)++;
    fileData = realloc(fileData, ((*fileDataLen)+1) * sizeof(struct fileInfo*));

    return fileData;
}
```

I notice, however, that after a few calls to func2(), there is a memory leak and fileData points to nothing. I'm just not sure where the leak is coming from, since I don't free anything in func2(). I'm assuming there are some `realloc` shenanigans, but I don't understand why. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.mcrun) to find the memory leak. FYI, it's much more efficient to initialize the array to some size `n` using `fileData = calloc(sizeof(struct fileInfo *), n)`. Then when you run out of space in the array, you realloc to `n*2`. This way you avoid reallocating every time you add a file info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm noticing a couple oddities in the code.

First, the function signature of `openFile` has a return-type of `void`, yet you check for a return-value here:

```
if (openFile(file, &buf, fileData, fileDataLen) < 0)
```

Secondly, as Peter also points out, you're not allocating enough space when calling `realloc`:

```
fileData = realloc(fileData, (*fileDataLen) * sizeof(struct fileInfo*));
```

On the first iteration, where `(*fileDataLen) == 0`, after incrementing `*fileDataLen`, you now only have a value of `1`, which means that you aren't reallocating anything (i.e, you're simply passing back the memory that `fileData` was already pointing to since it hasn't changed the size of the allocated array).  Therefore the next time you call `fileData[(*fileDataLen)] = currFile;` during another recursive call, you are going to be copying the value of `currFile` into `fileData[1]`, but that memory hasn't been allocated yet.  Furthermore, the next-time that `realloc` is called, it may not longer reallocate memory at the same location, so `fileData` will be pointing to a completely different location, with only the first array entry copied over.

Third, you can't call `free(fileData)` in `func1()` since you, by calling `realloc` inside your `func2()` function, have changed the value of where the memory is pointing, and you are not passing the actual memory address for the original `fileData` variable by reference to your `func2()` function.  In other words if the call to `malloc()` in `func1()` returned a value of let's say 0x10000, and you called `realloc` on that allocated memory somewhere else in the code, the memory that was allocated at 0x10000 has now moved somewhere else, but the value of `fileData` in the context of the local scope of `func1()` is still 0x10000.  Thus when you effectively call `free(0x10000)`, which is what's happening when you call `free(fileData)`, you are going to get an error since the memory for the array is no longer allocated at 0x10000.  In order to free the array, you are either going to have to return the updated pointer to the pointer array from all the recursive calls to `func2()`, or pass `fileData` by reference, meaning the function signature of `func2()` and `openFile()` will need to change to a `fileInfo***` type, and you'll also need an extra layer of indirection whenever accessing `fileData` in `func2()` and `openFile()`.  Then when you call `realloc` anywhere else, you are actually modifying the value of `fileData` as it was allocated in `func1()` as well, and can call `free()` on that pointer.

Finally, keep in mind that if you only free the memory allocated for `fileData`, you are going to have a big memory leak for all the allocated `fileInfo` nodes on the heap since `fileData` was only an array of pointers to the nodes, not the actual nodes themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome post. I updated my code to reflect the actual code more precisely and incorporate your suggestions. The issue I'm getting, however, is that fileData is still not pointing to the realloc'd memory block. I feel like I'm doing it correctly, but is there any issue with the new code?

Comment: You're loosing the reference to `fileData` because you are not passing that variable by reference.  In order to pass a `fileInfo**` to a function by reference, you would have to take the address of `fileData` to `func2()` and `openData()` ... that would also require a `fileInfo***` argument-type, and an extra layer of indirection when working with `fileData` inside of `func2()` and `openData()`.

Comment: I understand that, but in `checkForLoops()`, I'm passing in a `fileInfo **` and returning a `fileInfo **`. Since I have `fileData = checkForLoops()` in `func2()`, I should be able to preserve the pointer to the realloc'd memory, no?

Comment: Yes that will preserve the pointer, but that won't work going from `func2()` to `func1()`.

Comment: ahh of course! Thank you so very much!! Out of curiosity, how do you go about analyzing code? Is it just from experience, or are there specific things you look at when trying to determine the issue? I'm trying to be a better programmer, so I'd really like to improve my error correction

Comment: For me, it's basically come down to a combination of experience and learning from my mistakes, especially with pointers.  In well-managed code, pointers should not be very hard to manage, but it will still take some good book-keeping to keep track of where they're pointing to and freeing any memory that is being pointed to when you're finished.  That being said, for analyzing code, once you run into pointer problems, I typically work backwards from where the problem occurred, since for most cases involving pointers, where the problems become visible are not where the real bug is.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your problem is that you aren't allocating enough memory for `fileData`:</strike>

<strike>fileInfo **fileData = malloc(sizeof(struct fileInfo*));</strike>

Here you only allocate memory for a *single pointer to* `fileInfo`, instead of the array of `fileInfo` instance you seem to be using.

Sorry, my first idea was wrong... but your problem still seems to be that you aren't allocating enough memory for `fileData` - just in a different place:

```
fileData[(*fileDataLen)] = currFile; // 1
(*fileDataLen)++;
fileData = realloc(fileData, (*fileDataLen) * sizeof(struct fileInfo*)); // 2
```

Here you allocate one element less than needed. You start with `fileDataLen` of 0, and `fileData` containing 1 element. After opening the first file, you increment `fileDataLen` to 1, then reallocate the array to contain 1 element instead of 2! Thus, when opening the 2nd file, your buffer is overrun at `// 1` above, and some memory is overwritten.

You should keep this invariant at all times, reallocating the array to a size `fileDataLen + 1`:

```
fileData = realloc(fileData, (*fileDataLen + 1) * sizeof(struct fileInfo*));
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much - this was a big mistake on my part! After fixing that, storing the pointers works fine, but I'm getting an invalid free at `free(fileData)`. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of processing you're performing over path variable in func2, but you might be trying to modify a static string, which will lead you to another memory problem since those kind of strings are stored in a private memory zone reserved by the OS.

Comment: None of the strings are static.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I was confused by this line: `char * path = "path of file"` but I guess that was just an example.